# printing "action not found". While "availaiblebooksbooks" should print

Tags: java

i want to print my `availaiblebooksbooks` array. I am doing this using for loop.

initial output

```
welcome..., what do you want to do in library
choose any one performable action
1.addbook
2.purchasbook
3.returnbook
4.showavilaiblebook
```

I am putting user input `4.showavilaiblebook`

after putting input is m getting this.

```
action not found
action not found
action not found
```

where it should print:-

```
Think and grow rich

how to influence pepoles

Richest man in bablyon

Jeet ya har

great words win heart

Time management

positive thinking

power thinking

subconcious mind
```

My java code

```
  public class OnlineLibrary {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("welcome..., what do you want to do in library");
       
       String [] actionlist = {"choose any one performable action", "1.addbook","2.purchasbook","3.returnbook","4.showavilaiblebook"};
       for(int i = 0; i<actionlist.length; i++) {System.out.println(actionlist[i]); }
       
       
       //list of library books
       String [] availaiblebooksbooks = {"Think and grow rich", "how to influence pepoles", "Richest man in bablyon", "Jeet ya har", "great words win heart","Time management", "positive thinking", "power thinking","subconcious mind"};
       
       String input = scan.next();
       for(int i = 1; i<actionlist.length; i++) {
           String actionno = actionlist[i];
           
           
           
           if (input.equals(actionno)) {  }
           else if (input.equals(actionno)) {  }
           else if (input.equals(actionno)) {  }
           else  if (input.equals(actionno)) { for(int p = 0; p<availaiblebooksbooks.length; p++) { System.out.println(availaiblebooksbooks[p]); }} 
           else {System.out.println("action not found");}
       }
      
    }

}
```

The expected answer is obtained by keeping its direct value of the arrayitem. But I want to know what is the problem with this.

Comment: Why all those `if`s with the same condition? If `input.equals(actionno)` is true, then only the first (empty) one gets executed.

Comment: `if (input.equals(actionno)) {  }` — What's the purpose of this?

Comment: Do you realize that your if-else chain contains `input.equals(actionno)` as every condition?

Comment: # MCEmperor :- Now i will write more code here

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, or use a switch statement based on the "input":

```
       String input = scan.next();
       if (input.equals("4")) {
           for(int p = 0;p < availaiblebooksbooks.length; p++) { 
               System.out.println(availaiblebooksbooks[p]);
           }
       }... else if (otherinputs) {
       .
       .
       }
```